# How can I resolve a problem with firebase registration?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm writing an application that have to register a user with firebase and than do the login. I wrote a function for the registration but the output give me this error:

PlatformException(error, Given String is empty or null, null)

This is the function:

```
 Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()));
      print(user);
      return user;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: On which line do u get that error?

Comment: Check if email and password are null